# Save excel file with dataframe name if in a function

Tags: r

Simple question but how do you save the name of a dataframe as the excel filename if it's in a function?

```
export_origin <-  function(df){
 df1 <- unite(df, variable, c(Reaction.Type, Trial, Actual.Total.Seconds)) 
 df2<- dcast(df1, X.nm.~variable, value.var = "X.A.")
 fname= paste(df, "xls", sep = ".")
 write.xlsx2(df2, file = fname, col.names = TRUE)}
```

I want fname=df.xls with whatever the df name is that I input but it saves it as the observations within the dataframe as the name.

Comment: If you want to get the name as a string use `substitute(df)`

Comment: What other packages are you using? I guess `unite` is from `dplyr` and `dcast` is from `reshape2`. But where does `write.xlsx2` come from? I think you might want to add more details.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `deparse(substitute`

```
export_origin <-  function(df){
    v1 <- deparse(substitute(df))
    df1 <- unite(df, variable, c(Reaction.Type, Trial, Actual.Total.Seconds)) 
   df2<- dcast(df1, X.nm.~variable, value.var = "X.A.")
   fname= paste(v1, "xls", sep = ".")
   write.xlsx2(df2, file = fname, col.names = TRUE)}
  }
```

To make this reproducible,

```
export_origin <-  function(df){
    v1 <- deparse(substitute(df))
    paste(v1, "xls", sep=".")
 }

export_origin(df)
#[1] "df.xls"
```

Comment: That's a brilliant answer that I've never came across! Thanks!